# No actualiza la formula llenando la celda desde oleDb c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel, oledb

Buenas tengo este problema.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy llenando los datos de la columna Especie por código c#, pero al momento de descargar el archivo modificado y abrirlo no ejecuta la formula hasta que hago un cambio en esa celda.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour], leas [ask] y agregues un [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Saludos

Comment: Buenas, sin el código, poca cosa podemos hacer, que no sea hacer de adivinos

Comment: Hola no hay necesidad, de poner el código c# ya que es un problema de Excel directamente. en la imagen pongo a vista la formula que fue llenada en c# pero no ejecuta la formula cuando abro el excel, y eso es porque c# lo llena como un texto simplemente y excel no lo reconoce como si fuera formula a eso quería llegar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi solución fue crear una macros que se ejecute al iniciar poniendo la formula en cada celda que yo necesite.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Worksheets("IMPORTAR).Activate
Range("B2:B501").FormulaLocal = "=SI.ERROR(BUSCARV(IMPORTAR!$C2;DATA_ESPECIES!$A:$B;2;FALSO);"""")"
End Sub
```

Comment: Corrige la respuesta, pon el código con su respectivo formato y no como una imagen.